# How to verify different pay-out methods in a Marketplace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, payment-gateway, stripe-payments, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments

Like mentioned on AirBnb how is it possible to Automate Different Pay-out statuses before they are available for suppliers to withdraw earnings?

https://www.airbnb.com/help/article/106/how-long-does-it-take-a-payout-method-to-become-ready

The problem is : How do we verify the Payout-Methods automatically?
For example how do we verify if the Bank Account Exists or If the Account number is correct to make sure we deposit a correct account.

Or how do we automatically verify a paypal that it exists?

Comment: Please elaborate your problem. Looks like you have put question at wrong place.

Comment: The problem is : How do we verify the Payout-Methods automatically? For example how do we verify if the Bank Account Exists or If the Account number is correct to make sure we deposit a correct account.

Or how do we automatically verify a paypal to make sure it exists r?

This is the reason Airbnb verifies it to make sure they dont send to a wrong account.

Comment: managed account bank accounts don't get verified until you try to transfer money to them. You could look at a service like Plaid